# Хочу использовать обьект db для db.getCollection('first'), но как получить этот обьект db?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Хочу использовать обьект db для db.getCollection('first'), но как получить этот обьект db?

Вот как подключаюсь к базе:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test-express', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
});
```

Comment: У объектов `mongoose` нет метода `getCollection`. Если он Вам действительно нужен, и не нужна функциональность `mongoose`, то, может, надо вместо него просто использовать `mongodb`?

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под " использовать mongodb"? Подключиться к базе через "mongodb"?

Comment: Да. Потому что, судя по вопросу, Вы не пытаетесь использовать возможности `mongoose`, но зато хотите использовать функции, предоставляемые непосредственно драйвером.

Comment: Окей, я подключился к базе через mongodb, как оттуда достать обьект db?

Comment: Как-то так: `const db = (await MongoСlient.connect(uri, options)).db('myDatabase')`

Comment: такой вариант не работает, не могу получить доступ к методу getCollection

Answer (score 1):

Как и многие, рекомендую почитать документацию к нужному драйверу. Mongoose я не знаю, работаю с драйвером mongodb, вот решение:

Подключаемся к mongodb:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myproject';
let client = await MongoClient.connect(connectionString,
        { useNewUrlParser: true })
const db = client.db(dbName)
```

Получаем коллекцию и находим документы:

```
const collection = db.collection('first');
// Find some documents
let allDocs = await collection.find({}).toArray()
```